# How to call functions in other PHP files?

Tags: php, file, methods, reference

I am trying to call a function from one file to another in PHP, however, I am getting the following error:

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined method SQLite3::print_model_query_form()

I have two files. The first - `dbfunctions.php` contains the method `print_model_query_form()`.
The second file `query_models` contains the following code:

```
include_once("functions/dbfunctions.php");
$db = new SQLite3('D:\xampp\sim\htdocs\dis_sqlite_database\disSQL3.db');
print $db->print_model_query_form("query_models.php");
```

The function looks a little like this:

```
function print_model_query_form($action, $current_values = 0){
    $db = new SQLite3('D:\xampp\sim\htdocs\dis_sqlite_database\disSQL3.db');

    if($current_values){
        // set to previous values.
    }else{
        // get POST values.
    }

    // Code to print query form.
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How can we possibly help without knowing what is in `functions/dbfunctions.php` The error message tells us that method is not in that class and the PHP interpreter does not make mistakes about these things

Comment: @RiggsFolly Apologies. I'm still relatively new to coding! `dbfunctions.php` contains a number of different functions. `print_model_query_form` is definitely present in the file. What steps can I take to debug this issue?

Comment: Is it a **function** or a **method of a class** You are calling it as a method of a class

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not quite sure, sorry. At the top of my file I declare `class dbfunctions`. Enclosed within this class is `function print_model_query_form`.

Comment: At least show us a basic prototype of `print_model_query_form`

Comment: So try calling it like it was just a simple function and see if that will work `print print_model_query_form("query_models.php");`

Comment: Just tried that...

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function print_model_query_form`

I will try to type up a simplified version now. Sorry to be such a pain.

Comment: Go for it we can wait

Comment: I have added the function to the original question. There's really nothing special in it.

Comment: Well that does not look like a class method so it should be called as a simple function. But this is looking like the include did not work. So try chnaging the `include_once("functions/dbfunctions.php");` to `require_once("functions/dbfunctions.php");` and if that fails it will throw an obvious error

Comment: Strange. I'm still getting the same error. Must be something I am doing wrong on this end. If I find out what was wrong I will let you know, thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only hit fatal error on 3rd line, **$db** should be instantiated successfully. So, the issue should be the **print_model_query_form** method.

Referring to [PHP:SQLite3 - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3.php)

, there is no such built in method called **print_model_query_form**.

[Edit 1]
Try to use **require_once** instead of **include_once** to make sure you have included *dbfunctions.php* successfully.

[Edit 2]
Check If you are using PHP's built in SQLite3 class (check your *php.ini* for *extension=php_sqlite3.dll* or *extension=php_sqlite3.so*).

If this is the case, check your *dbfunctions.php* for:-

- `class Something`
- `new SQLite3`
- `function print_model_query_form`

If all the above exists then you should replace your 2nd line with,
`$db = new Something(..);`

Note: It would be better if you can show *dbfunctions.php* instead or letting us make assumptions based on guessing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I have checked everything up to your last point where you say I should replace the second line. What exactly do you mean I should replace it with `new Something(..)`? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, `dbfunctions.php` is over 2000 lines of code containing many different functions.

Comment: `Something` is referring to the class in `dbfunctions.php` that owns the `print_model_query_form` method.